# Removing a sprite in an if statement with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, macos, sprite-kit

I want to make a game where every time a user touches, it switches between one of two "states". In order to keep track of touches, I made a variable called userTouches, which changes from true to false each time a user touches. I want to make it so that if numberOfTouches is true, it updates the texture to state0; if it's false, it updates the texture to state1. Pretty much just toggling between state0 and state1 for each touch.

```
   var userTouches: Bool = true


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */


    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        userTouches = !userTouches

    }



    let centered = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)





    let state0 = SKTexture(imageNamed:"state0")


    let state1 = SKTexture(imageNamed:"state1")


    var activeState: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: state0)

    //Add new state0 if it's odd, remove old state0 if it's not.
    if userTouches == true {
       activeState.texture = state0
    println("IT'S TRUE")
    } else {
        activeState.texture = state1
    println("IT'S FALSE")
    }

  self.addChild(activeState)
    activeState.name = "state0"
    activeState.xScale = 0.65
    activeState.yScale = 0.65
    activeState.position = centered

}
```

When I run the code, the new textures are added according to the conditions, but the old ones are still there. They are being added as new spritenodes in the scene. I do not want this. I was expecting it to simply switch between the textures (`state0` and `state1`) of the `activeState` spritenode depending on my boolean variable. How can I have my code toggle between textures each time a user taps, instead of piling new spritenodes on top of one another?

Comment: Try doing some `println()` logs and telling us what's happening. Like inside your if-statements, to make sure they're actually getting called at all. Also, I wouldn't use integers for the conditionals. I would use a Boolean, instead. Using `true` or `false` is much easier, in my opinion.

Comment: I edited my code according to your suggestion (the boolean), and it still has similar problems. I also tried making it so that a single spritenode would switch between two textures, but that doesn't seem to be working. The `println()` test worked, so I know my if statement is in fact being called.
I posted my new code to help you see what's going on.

Comment: You do not understand the basic error. You create local objects and add it to the scene. At next time you create the new local object and work with new local object. In you code you do not have access to old object that was created on last step. Check the answer that I left below and try to understand exactly what you're doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you create a new object, change its texture (a new object`s texture, but not the texture of object which was set up last time) and add it to the scene. That's why new objects are added and nothing happens with the old objects. 
Do this and it will solve your problem:

1. Create textures and SKSpriteNode object outside the `touchesBegan` function
2. If you have no init at your scene, create SKSpriteNode object at `didMoveToView` function for example and add it to scene
3. Then in `touchesBegan` function only set texture to SKSpriteNode object

it would look something like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
...
    let state0 = SKTexture(imageNamed:"state0")
    let state1 = SKTexture(imageNamed:"state1")
    var activeState: SKSpriteNode?

...
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {        
        let centered = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
        activeState = SKSpriteNode(texture: state0)
        self.addChild(activeState!)
        activeState!.name = "state0"
        activeState!.xScale = 0.65
        activeState!.yScale = 0.65
        activeState!.position = centered
    }
...
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if userTouches {
           activeState!.texture = state0
        } else {
           activeState!.texture = state1
        }
    }
...
}
```